# How to cross check data in different Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I make sure that the postcode corresponding to a name in worksheet 1 matches the address for the same name in worksheet 2.

For example, I would need a column with a vlookup or index/match formula that would check `Alice`'s postcode from worksheet 1 against `Alice`s postcode in worksheet 2 and return true for a match of the postcode or false if the postcode is different.

Worksheet 1

```
Name   Address  DOB  Post code
Alice  Berlin   1980 W2
Bob    London   1979 EC1
```

Worksheet 2

```
Name  Address Post Code DOB
Alice London  EC        1979
Alice Berlin  W2        1980
```

I don't think a vlookup is ideal because of performance and column positioning.

Comment: ```=VLOOKUP($A2,'Worksheet 2'!$A2:$C3,3,FALSE)=$D2)``` put this in Worksgeet 1 and drag it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is any other way to check that, other than `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` function family. What I would recommend is to use the X-function family (`XLOOKUP` or `XMATCH`), this is what Microsoft [recommends](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1#)

For example:

```
=XLOOKUP(D3,$C$8:$C$9,$B$8:$B$9)=B3
```

Then drag down the formula.

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

Answer (score 0):

Use a IF formula

For example in Sheet2 :  =IF(B5=Sheet1!B5,"True"'"False")

[Here is a link that might help](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-compare-two-columns-matches-differences/)

Comment: this solution if great, but it only works if both elements are in the same row position in different sheets, when that is not the case you need to search for it.